# Adding a typescript interface to Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

I'm learning angular and for best practice I think I need to add an interface to the output. The service `DataFetchService` is taking objects from an internal `.json` file. What is the best way to implement my interface to this code? Any resources on the matter are more then welcome

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataFetchService } from '../userActions';

interface getDataInterface {
  name: string;
  surename: string;
  }

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-from-server',
  templateUrl: './data-from-server.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-from-server.component.css']
})
export class DataFromServerComponent implements OnInit {

  users$: Object;

  constructor(private data: DataFetchService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getData().subscribe(
      data => this.users$ = data
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be super clear, interfaces are **not** present in the transpiled JS. If you need it to then you need an `abstract` class.

That said the purpose of an interface in cases like this is to provide type safety, so you should be strongly typing your data:

```
users$: getDataInterface; //Could be getDataInterface[] based on the names...
constructor(private data: DataFetchService) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.data.getData().subscribe(
  (data: getDataInterface) => this.users$ = data
  )
}
```

As an aside; classes and interfaces typically use PascalCase in TypeScript so your interface should be `GetInterfaceData`